# How to comment out an attribute

Tags: html

Looks like `<!--   -->` is not working for commenting out the `placeHolder` attribute in the following statement

```
<input type="number" placeHolder="Surface Thickness (mm)"/>
```

Like this:

```
<input type="number" <!--placeHolder--> title="Surface Thickness (mm)"/>
```

Is it possible to comment out the `placeHolder` attribute? Is there any method?

Comment: what server side tech are u using ? If you are using asp.net mvc then `@*placeHolder="test"*@`. In short use server side commenting if you are using any server side tech.

Comment: What's the point in *commenting out* an attribute?

Comment: @DotNetDreamer Node.js

Comment: @TJ Want to be able to switch between `placeHolder` and `title` attributes

Comment: @user4838962 then just remove one and add another. I don't see any pointing keeping it commented.

Answer (score 2):

You may not place comments `<!-- comment -->` inside HTML tag but you can add/change/remove attributes of HTML element using `elem.setAttibute('some','value')` or `elem.removeAttribute('some')`.
As to the question,

```
document.getElementById('someInput').removeAttribute('placeholder')
```